# Typeorm default select relation column

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have have those entities:

```
    @Entity('element')
    export class Element {
      [...]
      
      @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.createdElements)
      createdBy: User;
    }

    @Entity('user')
    export class User {
      [...]
      
      @Column()
      username: string;
    
      @OneToMany(() => Element, (element) => element.createdBy)
      createdElements: Element[];
    }
```

I want to get `Element` but always load 'element.user.username'.

```js
this.elementRepository.createQueryBuilder('element')
  .leftJoin('element.user', 'user')
  .addSelect('user.username')
  .getMany()
```

It does work with a query like that but is it possible to somehow describe this inside the entity file that `user.username` should be selected by default?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can load specific column, but what you can do is to make the relationship eager, by adding :

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.createdElements, {
        eager: true,
    })
```

elements will be loaded with their users

*ps:it's works only with find function*

```
const elements = await elements Repository.find()
```

otherwise, if you don't want that, I suggest creating a function that loads the specific columns you want you re-use it in you application:

```
function loadElements(){
 return this.elementRepository.createQueryBuilder('element')
.leftJoin('element.user', 'user')
.addSelect('user.username')
} 
// than you can use it in your app:
this.loadElements.where('id',1).getMany();
```